# How to unregister a resource class in jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am looking for a way to unregister an already registred base class in jersey.

Let's say for example I have those elements

```
@Path("a")
class A {}

Class ConfigA extends jersey.server.ResourceConfig...{
    public ConfigA {
      register(A.class)
    }
}
```

I want to create a new class B that will extend the class A in order to override something.

```
@Path("a") //SAME PATH as A
Class B extends A{}
```

Given that i don't have a direct access to the class ConfigA  I try to do something like that.

```
Class ConfigB extends ConfigA{
      public ConfigB(){
        super();
        //TODO Unregister the class A
        register(B.class)
      }
}
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Seems everything is unmodifiable at construction time.

Comment: Hi Paul, what do you mean ? no way to do what i am looking for ?

Comment: You can get a set of all the classes that you registered but all those sets are unmodifiable. I could see you using an application listener and removing it after all initialization is done, but that seems like a bit much.